# How to send mail if they didn't used the module at all in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, database, laravel, email

Basically, I want send a reminder to the user to used modules in the system. If the didn't used one of the module means need remind them by sending an automated mail. I have created a DB table which contain user_id, module_id and last_used_module. So How i will send the mail to the user.

I try to used null value for last_used_module but its didn't work because last_module_used time is the same with created at and updated at. So, i cant used that.Anyone can help with this?

**I got some idea to solve this issue which is if user_id and module_id exist in table means no need to the mail. I don't know hw implement this**.

```
 foreach($ModuleAutoMail as $module) {
                                if($mail->condition_id=='3' ){   

                                $last_used_module = Carbon::parse($module->last_used_module);
                                $DeferenceInDays = Carbon::parse(Carbon::now())->diffInDays($last_used_module);


                                if(is_null($last_used_module)){ 
                                    $ableToSendMail = true;
                                }
                                elseif ($DeferenceInDays > 7) {
                                    $ableToSendMail = false;
                                }
                                else {
                                    if ($emailCheck< 1){  
                                        $ableToSendMail = true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if ($ableToSendMail) { //saving and sent email
                        $mails = new EmailSave;
                        $mails->user_id = $user->id;
                        $mails->email_id =$mail->id;
                        Mail::to($user->email)->send(new Automail($mail));
                        $mails->save();
                    }
```

Comment: I didn't get your problem, do you want to send an email to user that's not used your module ?

Comment: ya... We have 50++ module in our system so the user should utilise it. If the didnt used one of the module means need remain the thm by an automated mail

Comment: Ok, so you have to update last_used_module every time he uses the module. Then, you can make your verifications.

Comment: Just one thing: your variable should be 'differenceInDays'. Also try to use camelCase on variables :)

Comment: what is camelCase on variables?

Comment: It will updated automatically in DB table

Comment: camelCase: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case

Comment: So, what's your main problem? Why you can't use last_used_module ?

Comment: last_used_module, created_at and updated_at always have same value in which i believe it is also filled so it is never null. This should be the reason why it is always break. I can't think other solution also.

Comment: So, I think the update of last_used_module it's broken, if there is a update the updated_at should be other value than created_at. Verify if this update it's correct.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get it.

Comment: Couldn't you just set your `last_used_module` to null when you first create your module?

Comment: I think cant like that. But i have an idea which is if user_id is not exist means thn send mail for each module else if user_id exist thn need check which module_id is not exist thn send mail.

Answer (score 0):

Mail Trap

1. Register on Mail Trap
2. Copy the SMTP login password form Mail trap
3. Paste in ENV file
4. Create Mailable

> Mail::send('emails.reminder', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use
>   ($user) {
>                   $m->from('hello@app.com', 'Your Application');
>                   $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Your Reminder!');
>               });

[Visit This Tutorial](https://medium.com/@christianjombo/setting-up-mailtrap-for-laravel-development-313133bb800c)